# GET http://localhost:8080/customer/src/components/manufacturer_conn.php 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I'm new to vue.js and i'm trying to connect vue.js to my database.

I wanna create a website, to see all my manufacturers from my db.

I did a little research and saw that i could use axios to get a file,but the path that i passed along doesn't work.

Here's my folder:

```
  customer
     src
       components
           hello_world.vue
        sql
           manufacturer_conn.php
           connection.php
```

this is my hello_world.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
   <div v-for="manufacturer in manufacturers"  v-bind:key="manufacturer">
     {{manufacturer}}
     {{text}}
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios');

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
 data:function(){
   return{
    manufacturers: ['hi','hello','to','you'],
    text: 'hi-------',
   }
  },

  beforeCreate(){
     axios.get('customer/src/sql/manufacturer_conn.php')
      .then(function (response) {
         app.manufacturers = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error);
      });
  },
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

this is my manufacturer_conn.php code:

```
<?php
 console.log('--hi--');
include 'config.php';

$manufacurer = mysqli_query($con,"select * from manufacurer");

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($manufacurer)){

   $response[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

ERROR:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/customer/src/sql/manufacturer_conn.php 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:59)
```

seems like my path is not right,can't figure out what it should be.

Comment: If you hit this link is it working? `http://localhost:8080/customer/src/sql/manufacturer_conn.php`

Comment: when i run this link  i get an error ```customer/src/sql/manufacturer_conn.php:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)```           But it do see my index page

Comment: @AntonyMN could you please help me?

Comment: Don't reference a link using the root file but rather, use the actual link, that is, the same one that can be seen on the browser if its a get request. Remember axios works with api endpoints, not actual file